# SQL Query filtering records

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a query to show Jobquotes that are not awarded (`awarded: false`). 
The code below is working well, but I have other Jobquotes that are awarded (`awarded: true`) with the same job.id. I was wondering if there was a way to filter the results to remove any Jobquotes that have the same job.id where one of them is awarded.

- a Job has many Jobquotes
- Jobquotes is a join table between Jobs and Quotes
- `awarded` is in Jobquotes

  ```
  x = Jobquote.select('*, (total_cost/quote_qty) AS cost_each')
  .includes(job: [:part], quote: [:vendor])
  .where(awarded: false)
  .where.not("quotes.quote_number" => nil)
  .order("parts.number, cost_each")
  .group(:quote_id, "parts.number")
  ```

Comment: As a note, `where(awarded: false)` is a more general way of expressing this. `'f'` is Postgres specific.

Comment: Seems to me that a `Job` should be `awarded` based on a `Jobquote`. This would make the above logic simpler because you can select only jobs that have not been `awarded`. Do you have some type of flag for this?

Comment: The job has many quotes so there is a join table of jobquotes. So that specific quote for the job would be the one to be awarded.

Comment: `awarded` is part of `Quote` or part of `Jobquote`?

Comment: Jobquote.... sorry that wasn't clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this: (Please note I feel there is a better way to do this just can't think of anything right now)

```
class Jobquote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :quote
  scope :awarded_job_quotes, ->{ where(awarded: true)}
  scope :open_job_quotes, -> {
        awarded_job_ids = awarded_job_quotes.pluck(:job_id)
        where.not(job_id: awarded_job_ids)
        }
  scope :display_open_job_quotes, -> {
        open_job_quotes.select('*, (total_cost/quote_qty) AS cost_each')
        .includes(job: [:part], quote: [:vendor])
        .where.not("quotes.quote_number" => nil)
        .order("parts.number, cost_each")
        .group(:quote_id, "parts.number")
        }
end
```

You can then call as

```
 Jobquote.display_open_job_quotes
```

What this will do is look for all awarded jobs and then exclude all of them from the query by `job_id`. I then created a `scope`(`display_open_job_quotes`) to just return the requested data as I feel long query chains like this can be distracting in a controller.

**Note**:This will run an additional query to get the initial `job_ids`.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm a little confused about your **Note:**

Comment: @Beengie right now you are running a single query. This solution will run an initial query to collect all the awarded `job_ids` and then grab just the `job_id` and run your query after the fact. This creates 2 queries the initial one for `job_ids` followed by yours. I always like to notate when I am altering a procedure in a way that could change performance even if it is slight in nature.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were stating that I needed to add another query for the job_ids separate from the `open_job_quotes`... testing now...

Comment: @Beengie I can understand the confusion I changed the wording of my note to be a bit more clear.

Comment: I added `.select('*, (total_cost/quote_qty) AS cost_each')` and it is perfect. Thanks for the education on multiple levels.

Comment: @Beengie sorry lost that line somewhere I have added it back in for you glad it works.